# Python "for loop " with two arguments

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
for wp  in outsite and for k in  range(Iterations+1):
```

how can I use this,  this is not working ?
`outsite` is a list 
`k` for progress bar

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What is the expected behaviour of this? Do you want to iterate pairwise, i.e. ``k0, wp0``, ``k1, wp1``, or product wise, i.e. ``k0, wp0``, ``k1, wp0``, ..., ``k0, wp1``? If pairwise, how do you want to handle differences in length? Are you aware of ``zip`` and ``enumerate``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate both of them simultaneously you can use `zip`, like the following:

```
for wp, k in zip(outsite, range(Iterations+1)):
    ...
```

Comment: More Pythonic is `for k, wp in enumerate(outsite):`

Answer (score 1):

Loops can only be nested traditionally:

```
for wp  in outsite:
    for k in  range(Iterations+1):
        # do stuff
```

Only in [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) you can use the following structure:

```
lst = [x for y in outer for x in inner]
```

WRT scope, note that whatever expression `inner` is, it has access to `y`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for this:
Nested for loops:

```py
for wp in outsite:
    for k in range(Iterations+1):
        # code goes here
```

or an iterator:

```py
from itertools import product
for wp, k in product(outsite, range(Iterations+1)):
    # code goes here
```

Hope this helps!!